# How do I add a button to a JSOM generated list?

Tags: 2013, custom, jsom

I would like to add a button to a list that I am generating using JSOM on a SharePoint page. I want this button to trigger a link in a pop-up window that changes based on the ID of each item in the list.  I know how to do this getting the ID of the current page but I have run into problems with getting it to work with JSOM. Here is the relevant part of the code. I am pretty sure part of the problem is that there are too many quotation marks.

**Edit** I have fixed the quotation marks but the code still isn't working. When I debug it looks like dialogfunction is not being called. dialog function is in a seperate js file that I load with the page.

**Edit 2** Changing the double quotes to single quotes after the backslashes fixed the problem, now it works!

```
var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
listItemInfo += '<button onclick="dialogfunction(\'/sites/CustomSite/Doc%20Repository/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=""' + oListItem.get_id() + '\'); return false;">View Properties</button>' + '<strong>Name: </strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('FileLeafRef') + ' <strong>Title:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + ' <strong>Status:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('_Status') + '<br />';
    }
    $("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);
        },
```

Comment: you are quite right, look at this:
onclick="dialogfunction(\"/sites/CustomSite/Doc%20Repository/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id() + '\"); return false;"

Comment: You need to escape your string. Have a look at the Special Characters section over here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten about putting a backslash before extra quotation marks. But it is still not working. The button appears but when I click on it the page just reloads and I get an uncaught syntax error missing } from the second line of the code on my page, which is really odd because there is no code on the second line.